Can C#/Visual Studio naming rules be configured to flag single-letter prefixes?
The naming rule violations can be configured in VS via Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# > Code Style > Naming for camelCase and flag locals and parameters with unexpected prefixes like _IsVisible or m_Name, while allowing them for private fields.
IDE1006 Naming rule violation: Prefix 'm_' is not expected
IDE1006 Naming rule violation: Prefix '_' is not expected
However, locals/parameters erroneously prefixed with m but without the underscore such as
public void Method(int mValue)
{
    bool mLocalVar = false;
}

do not get flagged.
Can the naming rules be configured to consider an m prefix without _ to be a violation as well?

You can create your own code analyzer.
Create  code analyzer project:

In the first analyzer project, modify the function
        public override void Initialize(AnalysisContext context)
    {
        context.ConfigureGeneratedCodeAnalysis(GeneratedCodeAnalysisFlags.None);
        context.EnableConcurrentExecution();

        context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeNode, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxKind.VariableDeclarator);
        context.RegisterSyntaxNodeAction(AnalyzeParameter, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.SyntaxKind.Parameter);
    }

    private static void AnalyzeNode(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        var variableDeclaration = (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.VariableDeclaratorSyntax)context.Node;
        var variableName = variableDeclaration.Identifier.Text;

        if (variableName.StartsWith("m"))
        {
            var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, variableDeclaration.GetLocation(), variableName);
            context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
        }
    }
    private static void AnalyzeParameter(SyntaxNodeAnalysisContext context)
    {
        var parameter = (Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax.ParameterSyntax)context.Node;
        var parameterName = parameter.Identifier.Text;

        if (parameterName.StartsWith("m"))
        {
            var diagnostic = Diagnostic.Create(Rule, parameter.GetLocation(), parameterName);
            context.ReportDiagnostic(diagnostic);
        }
    }
}

Set warning or error:
private static readonly DiagnosticDescriptor Rule = new DiagnosticDescriptor(DiagnosticId, Title, MessageFormat, Category, DiagnosticSeverity.Warning, isEnabledByDefault: true, description: Description);

Modify the text in resx file:

In code fix project :
comment the fix code:
    // Register a code action that will invoke the fix.
    //context.RegisterCodeFix(
    //    CodeAction.Create(
    //        title: CodeFixResources.CodeFixTitle,
    //        createChangedSolution: c => MakeUppercaseAsync(context.Document, declaration, c),
    //        equivalenceKey: nameof(CodeFixResources.CodeFixTitle)),
    //    diagnostic);

Select vsix project as start project to test:

